# Bootstrap 3 How search form and button in the same line when toggle is activated

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, search, toggle

i'm use Bootstrap 3

i have some trouble in toggle...

now

search form

search button

i want

search form search button

http://jsfiddle.net/ejA27/

I want search form and button in same line

how do i fixed it??

```
        <form role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-right ">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control form-control-70">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info ">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

form-control-70 is custom css 
.form-control-70 {
  width: 70%;

}